# Cannot install unity game on android phone

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have just finished programming a very simple **2d platformer with Unity**, and wanted to test out my game by **installing the app on my Android device**, but it looks like it isn't working.

I have already **activated the developer options** in the settings of my phone. I have **installed the Android reccommended SDK, NDK and JDK** with Unity today (1.9 GB), even though i already had (maybe somehow different versions) all of them for Android Studio, because when browsing the right folders in ***Preferences - External tools*** this message was coming out:

> You are not using the reccommended Android SDK Tools, other versions are not officially supported.

Now that i have installed everything directly from the Unity Hub, only this message appears under the JDK line:

> JDK installed with Unity is based on OpenJDK 1.8.0_152.
>   Licence information is in the install folder (AndroidPlayer/Tools/OpenJDK).

Now, when I have my phone (huawei) connected with a USB cable to my computer, and go to ***File - Build Settings***, and have selected ***Android***, when i press ***Build And Run***, I choose where to make the **.apk** file, then press ***"Save"***, after a few seconds a message like this comes out:

```
"Make sure your device is plugged in.
If you are sure that the device is attached then it
might be USB driver issue, for details please check
'Android enviroment setup' section in Unity manual."
```

And after this i can only press **"ok"** (or it loops and shows the message above every time), and it does **neither build the exported game or run it on my android phone**.

I have checked the 'Android enviroment setup [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-sdksetup.html) but **cannot find any information that can fix my problem**.

**Any information or help is really appreciated**, as i would like to start programming for android on Unity as well!

-

(my unity version is the last stable, the ***2019.1.10f1***).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure you are targeting android in the build settings.
2. After enabling developer mode on your android phone, go to your phone's Settings>System>Developer or Settings>Developer. Find and enable "USB Debugging". You will likely need to accept an access request on your phone for your usb connection.
3. In Unity Editor go to the build settings and your phone should appear as a runnable device (right-hand side of the build settings dialogue box). There is a refresh device list button if needed. Once your phone is the selected run device, then you should be able to build and run. The application should automatically start running on your android phone once it is done building.

   If your device does not show as a runnable device option in the Unity Editor Build Settings dialogue box even after refreshing the list, then the likely culprits are: 
   USB Debugging is not enabled, your phone has not accepted the access request your computer sent, or as the tutorial you linked stated: "If you are developing on a Windows computer, you might need to install a device-specific USB driver. See the manufacturer website for your device for additional information."

Edit - It looks like you've already read a tutorial mentioning the USB Debugging setting, but I'll leave it in these steps for now, because this must be turned on each time Developer Mode is activated.

Comment: Thank you so much! For some reason it was not allowing information from my computer, but now it works! :)